# How to return a return value from Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I noticed this field in the Hangfire Dashboard for a succeeded job:

[image]

I would love to shove some data in there, to give me more information about what the job did.

How would I do that?

I have searched google, checked the Hangfire documentation etc, but with no luck - probably because "result" is a very tricky keyword to search for in this context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Result" field displays the output/result your method returns.

You can return a string or object and Hangfire will convert it to JSON.

Your "Result" field contains a serialization error, Hangfire is failing to serialize the returned object but without any code I cannot help you further.

Please see example screenshots below.

[image: Code:]
[image: Result:]
[image: Code:]
[image: Result:]

Comment: ...I have had so many problems trying to write to the Hangfire log int he past, I did not even consider that the solution could be so simple and straightforward. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

To programmatically get returned value, use `IMonitoringApi`.
E.g. Helper method to get `List<TReturn>`:

```cs
List<TReturn> GetReturnedItems<TReturn>(string jobId)
{
    IMonitoringApi jobMonitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
    JobDetailsDto job = jobMonitoringApi.JobDetails(jobId);
    string resultSerialized = job.History[0].Data["Result"];
    List<TReturn> returnedItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TReturn>>(resultSerialized);
    return returnedItems;
}
```