# Hangfire Job Description and Name Customization

Tags: customization, hangfire

I would like, if possible, to have some control on the job description and name. I tried to add the JobDisplayName to the Controller that is activating the job, also to the method that is being called to run in background but no luck.
Also the job description page is very polluted with unnecessary information that i would like to remove, or to format to a readable information.

[image: My intended customization]

In the A case, i would like to remove this, or to format it to a more readable format.
In the B case what can i do to output it to a human readable object?

Answer (score 0):

Issue A: there are quite a few bugs that have been opened but most of them suggest there is no way to update the information displayed there, but, you should follow the [Best Practices](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html) and keep the method and arguments small.

[Fix B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57951926/1390548)

Change the return statement of your method that's enqeued to fix the data displayed.

Comment: Well regarding to A, I have to pass a collection, in this case a list, since it's a file that has been parsed and passed as a collection to process, this file has only one line, i Imagine when it has a 1000 or 10 000 or so on, it's confusing to me that i couldn't work with collections.

When you say to change the return statement, if I want to display it using some formatted data, if i can use /n or new line characters, how does it solves my issue?