# How to get the return value from a method started in Hangfire?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

When starting a method using Hangfire the only value you get returned is the id of the Hangfire job privided by the Hangfire framework, but I need the return value of the method. How can I get the return value from the actual method?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ReturnValue());
}

public bool ReturnValue()
{
    return true;
}
```

I want to get the return value of the `ReturnValue()` method inside the `SomeMethod()`, is this possible and how can I do this? The value `true` is showing in the Hangfire Dashboard, but I want to use it int the code.
Something like this doesn't work:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    bool result = false;
    var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => result = ReturnValue());
}
```

While Googling for this problem I found other people with this problem. I found these solutions:

- [How to return a return value from Hangfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748867/how-to-return-a-return-value-from-hangfire)
- https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-catch-return-object-from-backgroundjob-enqueue/555/3
  But this was not a solution for me.

Comment: What is the point of starting background job if you want to wait it to return?

Comment: What's the use case you have for this? What work is the background job supposed to do, and why do you need the result of it to be returned to the method that enqueued the background job?

Comment: I want to run some sql queries form the method started in Hangfire, but if these queries fail for some reason I want to return this in the form of a bool value

Comment: I guess it is simply not possible to get the return value of a method/function started with Hangfire

Comment: It's not clear why you're using Hangfire then. The whole point of Hangfire is that you can enqueue some background work to be done and the code that enqueued the work can continue on its merry way. If you immediately block and wait for the Hangfire job to complete so you can obtain the result, then you might as well not use Hangfire in the first place to do the work. What you're asking for is possible to do, but makes no sense, so implementing it is completely pointless.

Comment: A common pattern is for some long running process to be enqueued, and your original code moves on. Then at the end of your Hangfire job, you would have some sort of mechanism for communicating the results back to the user. This could mean you insert some record in a database table with the results, and the user would see it later when they refresh. Or it could mean you implement some sort of polling logic, so that shortly after the result is available, it automatically appears. Or you could implement a push notification system with something like SignalR to send the results to the user.

Comment: The point is: you need to carefully consider what you're doing and architect your app accordingly.