# How to capture data created from within a Hangfire job?

Tags: c#, vb.net, hangfire

I'm generating some new data within my Hangfire job:

```
Public Sub Run() Implements IEngine.Run
  Dim oTemperature As Temperature
  Dim nFahrenheit As Decimal
  Dim nCelsius As Decimal
  Dim oRandom As Random

  oRandom = New Random

  nFahrenheit = (oRandom.NextDouble * 100.0) - 20.0 ' Random temperature between -20°F and +80°F '
  nCelsius = (nFahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0 ' Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius '

  oTemperature = New Temperature With {.Fahrenheit = nFahrenheit, .Celsius = nCelsius}

  Me.Context.Temperatures.Add(oTemperature)
  Me.Context.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

How do I get this new data from the job into my controller so I can display it on the page?

The official documentation doesn't seem to cover this, at least not as far as I can find. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57748867) purport to cover it, I believe, but if so I'm not understanding how to actually implement it.

Here's what I've got in my controller:

```
Dim oJob As IBackgroundJobClient
oJob = Me.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(GetType(IBackgroundJobClient))
oJob.Schedule(Of IEngine)(Sub(Engine) Engine.Run(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
```

I tried passing a DTO-like object to `Engine.Run()` and then assigning the new values there, but they didn't make it out for some reason.

Are those answers accomplishing what I'm after? If so, how would I integrate the solution into my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

My confusion stemmed from the fact that I'd glossed over a certain nuance: the `Schedule` function takes an `Expression(Of Action(Of IEngine))` and I was hung up on the false notion that it was referring to `IEngine.Run()`, thereby requiring *it* to be the `Action` in question.

I'm not sure where I came up with that idea, but it's what was holding me back.

Once I changed the `Run` method to a function, I was able to get the result in the manner described in [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57748867).